# Java GUI Table adding certain rows to a watch-list

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

Ok I'm designing an application that will be used by many users with a JTable where the data for the table is pulled in using JDBC. And I'm thinking of adding a watch-list so the user can keep an eye on certain rows in the table in the GUI. Here is my question though because I am pulling the data from JDBC for the table will I not need to create a database MySql table for every user using the application so that 1 user can add rows to a watch-list while other users can add other rows to the watch-list and exclude the rows that others might have included in their watch-list. Because my solution is adding an extra column in the database for a value for watch-list where this is true only display these rows where this is not true don't show. But this solutions involves creating a database table for every user which is not what I want what is another way to add these rows to a watch-list.

```
public class EmployeeSearchApp extends JFrame {
    private static  Connection connect;
    private JLabel title = new JLabel();
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField lastNameTextField;
    private JButton btnSearch;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JTable table;
    private JButton appartmentformbutton = new JButton();
    private JButton selectbutton = new JButton();
    private JButton logoutexitbutton = new JButton();
    private JComboBox  addresscb = new JComboBox();
    private JComboBox  sexcb = new JComboBox();
    private JComboBox  agecb = new JComboBox();
    private JComboBox coursecb = new JComboBox();
    private JComboBox jobcb = new JComboBox();  
    static String loginusername;
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;
    List<Employee> employees = null;
    static EmployeeSearchApp searchouse = new EmployeeSearchApp(loginusername);
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    searchouse.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public EmployeeSearchApp(String loginusername) {    
         this.loginusername=loginusername;
            if(loginusername!=null){
            System.out.print(loginusername);
            }
        // create the DAO
        try {
            employeeDAO = new EmployeeDAO();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error: " + exc, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
        }
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Search for house");
        setAutoRequestFocus(false);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        title.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        title.setText("               Looking for Appartment");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
        FlowLayout flowLayout = (FlowLayout) panel.getLayout();
        flowLayout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JLabel lblEnterLastName = new JLabel("Enter last name");
        panel.add(title);
        panel.add(lblEnterLastName);
        lastNameTextField = new JTextField();
        panel.add(lastNameTextField);
        lastNameTextField.setColumns(10);   
        logoutexitbutton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
            {
                Component frame = null;
                int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                        frame,
                        "Exit to Main Screen",
                        "Exit to Main Screen",
                        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                        searchouse.dispose();
                        intro  cancellogin = new intro();
                        cancellogin.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        addresscb.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Location", 
                "Willow View", "Carton Drive", "Ballykeeran", "Moydrum",
                "Valley Court", "Auburn Heights", "Cypress Gardens", "Old Willow Park", "Old Willow Place",
                "Willow Park", "Wellmount Apartments", "Erris Grove, Willow Park", "Willow Green",
                "Cartontroy", "Crystal Village", "Willow Grove", "Willow Cresent",
                "Thornbury Drive", "Willow Place, Willow Park", "Willow View", "Willow Drive",
                "Small Apartments", "Other"}));
        sexcb.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Sex", "Male", "Female"}));
        agecb.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Age", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40"}));
        coursecb.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Course", "Software Design", "Cooking", "Science" }));
        jobcb.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Job", "Guard", "Teacher", "Farmer" }));
        appartmentformbutton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        appartmentformbutton.setText("<html>Appartment<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Form</html>");
        logoutexitbutton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        logoutexitbutton.setText("Log Out");
        selectbutton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); 
        selectbutton.setText("Select Row");
        btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
        btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Get last name from the text field
                // Call DAO and get employees for the last name
                // If last name is empty, then get all employees
                // Print out employees              
                try {
                    String lastName = lastNameTextField.getText();
                    List<Employee> employees = null;
                    if (lastName != null && lastName.trim().length() > 0) {
                        employees = employeeDAO.searchEmployees(lastName);
                    } else {
                        employees = employeeDAO.getAllEmployees();
                    }
                    // create the model and update the "table"
                    EmployeeTableModel model = new EmployeeTableModel(employees);
                    table.setModel(model);
                    //model.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());
                    //DefaultListModel<String> defaultListModel = (DefaultListModel<String>)EmployeeTableModel.getModel();      
                    /*
                    for (Employee temp : employees) {
                        System.out.println(temp);
                    }
                    */
                } catch (Exception exc) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(EmployeeSearchApp.this, "Error: " + exc, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
                }   
            }
        });
        addresscb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
            {
                try {
                    String lastName = addresscb.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    System.out.print(lastName);
                    List<Employee> employees = null;
                    if (lastName != null && lastName.trim().length() > 0) {
                        employees = employeeDAO.searchEmployeesbyaddress(lastName);
                    } else {
                        employees = employeeDAO.getAllEmployees();
                    }       
                        EmployeeTableModel model = new EmployeeTableModel(employees);
                        table.setModel(model);
                } catch (Exception exc) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(EmployeeSearchApp.this, "Error: " + exc, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
                }   
            }
        });

//Add to arraylist where users id is equal to username only display these rows      
/*Create button on form
Add selected rows equal to Arraylist
Create an arraylist step 1 where users id ="bob"
Create button display
where users id="bob"
Display Arraylist*/

        selectbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /*int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
            //TableRowModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
    //      if(selectedRow != -1) {
                //table.removeColumn(table.getColumnModel().getSelectedColumn());
                table.getSelectedRow();
                //got selected row
                //database select Apartment get name and id
                //System.out.print(loginusername + ","+loginpassword);
                table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow());
                System.out.print(selectedRow);
                try {
                    // get the selected row
                    int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                    // make sure a row is selected
                    if (row < 0) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(EmployeeSearchApp.this, 
                                "You must select an employee", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);             
                        return;
                    }
                    JTextField releaseYearField = new JTextField();
                    //int decision = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, fields , "Create Dialog" , JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                    // prompt the user
                    int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                            EmployeeSearchApp.this, "Are you sure this is the appartment you want to choose, Please take note of phone number and address", "Confirm", 
                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                    if (response != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                        return;
                    }
                    // get the current employee
                    Employee tempEmployee = (Employee) table.getValueAt(row, EmployeeTableModel.OBJECT_COL);
                    //((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());
                    // delete the employee
                    employeeDAO.deleteEmployee(tempEmployee.getacc_id());
                    employeeDAO.updateEmployee(tempEmployee.getacc_id(), loginusername );
                    // refresh GUI
System.out.print(tempEmployee.getaddress());
                    // show success message
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(EmployeeSearchApp.this,
                            "Appartment confirmed request."+ 
                            "\n\nAddress: " + tempEmployee.getaddress()
                            + "\nHouse number: " + tempEmployee.gethouse_num()
                            + "\nLandlords Name: " + tempEmployee.getLandlords_first_Name()
                            + " " + tempEmployee.getLandlords_Surname()
                            + "\nLandlords phone number: " + tempEmployee.getMobile_Num(), "Error",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                } catch (Exception exc) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(EmployeeSearchApp.this,
                            "Error deleting employee: " + exc.getMessage(), "Error",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }

*/          
                 table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow()); 
            }});
        panel.add(btnSearch);
        panel.add(appartmentformbutton);
        panel.add(selectbutton);
        panel.add(logoutexitbutton);
        panel.add(addresscb);
        panel.add(sexcb);
        panel.add(agecb );
        panel.add(coursecb);
        panel.add(jobcb);   
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        table = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels all lines with white lines gone

Comment: Create a single table, link it to the user table (via key reference), it should have a column which indicates the row the user is interested in, you would then have multiple rows in the this table for each row a user is interested in.  This way, you can simply filter out the original table against the rows in the "wish list" table based on the current user

Answer (score 1):

Start by creating a new table (wish list)

In this table, have the following columns

- user key
- row key
- (optional) primary key (you could use the user key and row as a composite key instead if you wished)

For example

```
+----------+---------+-------------+
| user key | row key | primary key |
+----------+---------+-------------+
```

The user key would be linked back to the user table via a foreign key reference

The row key would be linked back to the data table view a foreign key reference.

This way you could query the data table and filter it using the current user

```
select * from data where rowKey in (select rowKey from wishList where data.rowKey = wishList.data and userKey = ?)
```

*(nb untested, but that's the gist)*

to get the rows the user is interested in

You can also set up the referential integrity in such away that when a row is deleted from the data table, it will be removed from the wish list table and you could do the same thing for the user table

Comment: that would work but I decided to store both usernames and the data in the same table so I could bypass using foreign keys and all that. So how would you add it to the wishlist where there is only 1 table.

Comment: What happens when more then one user wants to watch the same row?